# Python - import locally builded python wheel

Tags: python, pypi, python-wheel

Please, can anyone suggest why I am not able to import my [python library](https://github.com/romanzdk/beautify_table)?

Steps I do:

1. Go to `beautify_table` folder
2. Run `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`
3. Run `pip install dist/beautify_table-0.1-py3-none-any.whl`
4. Run `python` (either jupyter notebook or in terminal)
5. In python I run `import beautify_table`
6. I get an error: `No module named beautify_table`

Tried on following machines:

- Windows 10, python 3.9.5
- macOS 12.1, python 3.8.6

How is that? What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Now I am able to to `import beautify_table` inside python console (while being inside venv), however I am not able to `import beautify_table` when included in other module I want to run.

```py
#module_I_want_to_run.py
import beautify_table
```

Command: `python module_I_want_to_run.py`

Error:`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautify_table'`

Comment: I reproduced all steps inside a virtualenv with python 3.9.6, and it worked fine. Can you give more information?

Comment: `$ which python` and `$ which pip` could help you understand what's going on, I've got bamboozled by `pip` and `pip3` few years ago... `python` was python3, but `pip` was still related to python2.

Comment: Updated original question @RafaelMarques

Answer (score 1):

Your repository is having multiple issues!

- Instead of `app`, use `beautify_table` as the folder name. Otherwise you get this

```
$ pip freeze
beautify-table==0.1
$ python3
Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan 25 2022, 16:13:10)
[GCC Apple LLVM 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import beautify-table
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import beautify-table
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> import app
>>> dir(app)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

When I check `pip freeze` I see you pakage is installed but, I have do `import app` to use your resources

- Your requirements does not mention `pandas` in setup.py. Prefer using a `requirements.txt`

```
>>> from app import beautify
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/sam/beautify_table/app/beautify.py", line 22, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

- I suggest you to look into https://github.com/pypa/pip as a reference on how to package

Happy coding!